# GUI design & Software used in some movies

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm a java & php programmer, i'm curious about GUI design for software used in some movies I watched such as :

- Angel & Demons movie (CERN Software used by scientists)
- Skyfall (Software used by Ben Whishaw as Gadget-Master Q)
- And another high
  tech movies..

Those software look very nice & interactive, most of them use blue or green as their primary color and black for the background.

I'm very interested to develop application like that.

What programming language & tools needed to develop GUI & application like that ?

Any reference link I can visit regarding this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much any platform will allow you to customize the skin of your GUI - Flex, WPF, Android, iOS, and many others.

You know you definitely can create websites to mimic the look and feel of those UIs in movies, with some CSS and supplementary images, and just view it full screen.

Comment: Yup,, I've tried to build one on my local but it still needs more retouch. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can develop application like that with any GUI toolkit available these days. It will require a hell lot of custom coding. if i were to write something like that i would do it in WPF

Comment: GUI Toolkit, I'll look that one, thanks for the info :)